# How can I remove the border line of a MonthCalendar

Tags: vb.net, calendar, monthcalendar

I develop with VB2017 in Basic. I am wondering how to remove the border of a monthcalendar.
File attaches the calendar image and the code.

[image]

```
    Dim colorFore, colorBack As New Color
    colorFore = Color.FromArgb(181, 202, 146)
    colorBack = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20)
    SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar1.Handle, "", "") 'disable the visual style for the MonthCalandar control
    MonthCalendar1.BackColor = colorBack
    MonthCalendar1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    MonthCalendar1.TitleForeColor = colorFore
    MonthCalendar1.TitleBackColor = colorBack
    MonthCalendar1.TrailingForeColor = colorBack
    MonthCalendar1.Font = New Font(MonthCalendar1.Font.FontFamily, 24, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: You can acheieve this using css style property. Find this calender css propety and add margin-border:0px

Comment: I use Visual Basic language (Visual Studion 2017).